# Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress website shows the fatal error this how can I fix it?

Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in /home/truevisio/public_html/wp-includes/sodium_compat/lib/sodium_compat.php on line 2

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

From your file manager check if your sodium_compat.php 's first lines are similar to this [file](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/sodium_compat/lib/sodium_compat.php).

there should be no extra line between `<?php` and `namespace`.
if there are lines above `namespace Sodium;` maybe you have been hacked, you can take a look at [this page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/).

Comment: <?php
namespace Sodium;

require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/autoload.php';

use ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat;

/**
 * This file will monkey patch the pure-PHP implementation in place of the
 * PECL functions, but only if they do not already exist.
 *
 * Thus, the functions just proxy to the appropriate ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat
 * method.
 */